# How do set arrays for line parsing

Tags: c, file

I'm a little confused about how C reads a file. If I use fscanf to read a file (with multiple lines) and put it into an array[0]. Can I use an if statement to check for `\n` character and then let it continue to read the second line into array[1]? or will it repeat to read from the start of the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functions like these will always read from your current position (you can obtain this using `ftell()` for example). After reading, the current position is always updated/moved (except for a few functions stating the opposite). To change the position yourself, you can use `fseek()`. Side note: You shouldn't use `fscanf()` as the results might be unpredictable in case the format of the input isn't as expected.

Comment: What do you mean by functions like these? Should I use fgets instead?

Comment: It really depends on what you want to do. In general `fgets()` or `fread()` (and pretty much any such function other than `fscanf()`) are considered to be better/more secure. But especially for reading the file line by line `fgets()` should be the perfect choice (unless you want to use streams).

Comment: I going to use something I'm more familiar with, which is fgets(). Thanks

Comment: Also one more question. If I had a while loop to check for EOF `fgets(temp_airports, 150 , temp) != EOF` and then in that while loop I had an if `fgets(temp_airports, 150 , temp) == "\n"` will it continue to check where the first one left off?

Comment: There's nothing insecure about `[f]scanf` when used correctly (unlike `gets`, which really is inherently insecure). It's just harder to use correctly (in the sense that the format string can get pretty arcane) than `fgets`.

Comment: Well, shouldn't call it unsecure, just more unpredictable (in case you don't get what you expected; like you expect to read x bytes, but the file position isn't moved due to wrong stuff being there). Learning C: Just do something like `while(!feof(fp)) { fgets(line,150,fp); }`. Each call to `freadf()` will move the position, so don't call it twice for one line.

Answer (score 0):

First off, it is moderately hard work to get `scanf()` to read whole lines.  You'd be better off using `fgets()` for the job.  You also need to ensure you have enough memory for each line to be read into.

Note that the `scanf("%s",...)` means read characters up to the first white space (roughly, a word, not a line, unless the line happens to consist of just one word).

I might write:

```
enum { MAX_LINES = 10, MAX_LINESIZE = 256 };
char array[MAX_LINES][MAX_LINESIZE];
int i = 0;

while (i < MAX_LINES && fgets(array[i], sizeof(array[i]), stdin) != 0)
    i++;
```